# R6034: An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll

I am getting this R6034 error when running program that I just updated (and cleaned) from VS2003 -> VS2008. To be more exact:

> "R6034: An application has made an
>   attempt to load the C runtime library
>   incorrectly."

It seems to happed almost at the same place all the time when running. I have no really idea why but I tried some suggestions I found when googleing this. For example adding the msvc dlls, but that didn't work.

Any help on why this error occurs would be great. Thanks

Comment: I got the same error just building an app using mingw and then loading a DLL that was a bit more sophisticated.  Windows is making things a bit more complex than it needs to be for a simple quick command-line compile Linux-style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from Visual Studio 2005 you must refer to the C Run Time using a manifest file.
Referring to the DLL's by just putting them in the path will give the above error.

The manifest file will look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT' version='8.0.50727.4053' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

You can use the MT command to integrate the manifest as a resource in the application, but that's not mandatory.  It's also allowed to have the manifest besides your application (as MYAPP.EXE.MANIFEST).

Comment: okay, that makes somewhat sense. when i compile a new project using vs2008 <assemblyIdentity> ends up embedded in my .exe, but for this migrated project that part is not there at all. have i missed some project setting somewhere? or how do i get it in there for that project too?

Comment: I think that some of the C/C++ include files contain #pragma's that add a linker command so the linker generates the manifest.  Look for /manifestdependency in the C/C++ include files.  These should trigger the creation of the manifest file.

Comment: didn't find anything like that. wondering if it is better to just make a new vs2008 project and move everything over by hand.

Comment: See my other answer for a test program.

Answer (score 0):

The following test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <crtdefs.h>

void main()
{
std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

Compiled using these commands (Visual Studio 2005):

```
cl /EHsc /MD /c test.cpp
link test.obj
```

Create the executable (TEST.EXE) and a manifest file (TEST.EXE.MANIFEST) that looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.CRT' version='8.0.50727.4053' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

I didn't try this with VS2008, but this should probably work as well.

Hope this is enough to get you started.

Comment: still does not work for my "migrated" project. but works when im making a new one. i will just remake the whole solution. marking your first answer as an answer since it is basically it. thanks!